SqlAlchemy: Server settings in connection URL
I would like to disable the PostgreSQL JIT to improve ENUM datatype handling (PostgreSQL document:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#disabling-the-postgresql-jit-to-improve-enum-datatype-handling)
Related to the doc this can be achieved by passing:
"server_settings": {"jit": "off"}

As a connection arg during engine creation. My Problem is that I am not able to change the engine creation parameters as the creation is done internally by a third library. I can only provide the DB-URL!
My question here if it is possible to specifiy the server-settings in the URL?  Something like this:
postgresql+asyncpg://dbuser:dbpwd@server:5432/mydb?my_server_setting....

I tried several things like "....5432/mydb?jit=off". But it doesn't work!
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks

The library is prefect which internally uses sqlalchemy with asnycpg as driver.

one can see this in the error trace:        ----------------------------
packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 621, in connect
return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "/srv/venv/prefect-server/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 932, in connect
await_only(creator_fn(*arg, **kw)),
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jit'
Application startup failed. Exiting.
